# How can I protect myself from a prolific, abusive litigant?

Tags: liability

I would like to sell items online, and came across [this story about a person who sold a $40 printer](http://www.indystar.com/story/news/2016/06/06/he-sold-40-printer-then-he-sued-indiana-30000/85219140/) and ended up (so far) paying over $12,000 in legal fees.

What could I do to prevent this situation on a site like Craigslist?

Comment: Just some corrections, if you really want to base your question on an example. The legal fees have been reported to be "at least $12,000", not "over $30,000". The trial court's judgement in favour of the plaintiff was [reversed and remanded](http://www.in.gov/judiciary/opinions/pdf/05231602nhv.pdf30). The trial court has been instructed to consider dismissing the case under [Trial Rule 41(E)](http://www.in.gov/judiciary/rules/trial_proc/#_Toc425496430), which allows for "an order of dismissal at plaintiff’s costs".

Comment: Related: [Can someone more wealthy than me bury me in legal fees?](http://law.stackexchange.com/q/1628/10)

Answer (score 2):

Insurance

Professional indemnity indemnifies you against negligent advice, public & product liability against what it says, motor vehicle ... And so on. A good insurance broker will tell you what you need for your business.

When a claim is made against you, you make a claim on your insurer and, with your input, they decide to fight or settle.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a lawyer.

As part of the sale, require a signed contract that says all the things you want to say to protect yourself. Get a lawyer to write you one or look for examples. I won't actually write an example contract because that might look too much like unlicensed practice of law; however, you might look into the following kinds of clauses and use them (and/or others) when drafting your own:

- disclaimer of warranties of merchantability and fitness for purpose
- agreement not to hold you liable for damages resulting from defects
- limitation of liability, for instance to a token amount ($1.00) or the purchase price
- reformation and severability clauses to make sure the agreement is enforced to the maximum extent possible in any jurisdiction

Answer (score -2):

Before to sell I would have couple witnesses that the product that I am selling in a good and working condition