# How to sue big companies?

Tags: international, lawyer

I've heard before that some Lawyers in USA offer to defend people against big companies and they ask *only* for a percentage of the compensation (if they get any), otherwise they don't take any other fees.

Usually that happens (as per the source that I don't remember) for ridiculous reasons because these lawyers are trying to get business.

But for other people who even have good reasons to raise the lawsuit, how can they find a good recognizable lawyer in the USA to do this (if they are not from the USA)?

Comment: Reputable lawyers can agree to this sort of compensation arrangement (usually called "contingency," at least in the US) for non-ridiculous reasons.  For example, a poor person might have been wronged by a big company and have a strong case but be unable to obtain legal representation without such an arrangement.  But most lawyers will advise against suing a party for financial damages if the party lacks the means to pay, no matter how the lawyer's compensation is to be structured.

Comment: It's going to be really hard to get good legal representation in a lawsuit against a large company without contingency fees, but some people appear to see this as undesirable, and bad-mouth contingency fees by coming up with ridiculous lawsuits (and sometimes changing stories to make reasonable lawsuits look frivolous).

Comment: Note that even if your lawyer doesn't charge, if you run a case and lose you will be up for the costs of the other party's lawyers.

Comment: Possibly related Q&A: [Can someone more wealthy than me bury me in legal fees?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/1628/10)

Answer (score 1):

This is called a contingency arrangement, and it's very common, especially in civil rights and employment discrimination contexts.

If you want to find a lawyer, you should use Google. Just put in "employment discrimination lawyer" or "antitrust lawyer" or whatever you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all lawyers are registered with American BAR association, and you can simply look up which lawyer represents what and their rating. 
You can also check with the State Bar of any individual state.
Or, just stating the obvious, you can google for a type of lawyer that you need.

My suggestion to you, would be to do your own research. All law is just a click away, if you have internet.

To sue somebody, like a corporation, you need standing. Meaning, the corporation wronged you somehow in a legally cognizable way. This is what you meant by a good reason.

If your reason is sufficiently good, it is more likely that an attorney, would take your case, based on a future percentage. Otherwise whats the point on spending time on something that is not going to get you paid?

Significantly, websites like avvo.com offer free legal advise by attorneys, and you can see their rating when they respond. I presume the incentive is for them to find clients.

But... in the end no one will care more about your case than you. So do your own research.